# How do you mock a class function in componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocking, jestjs

```
class myClass extends React.Component {
     async componentDidMount(){
         const xyz = helperclass.queryParameters('parameter')
         // how can I mock xyz to help me change the value to test the conditional below
         if(xyz){
            // do something here
          }
     }
}
```

have edited the code above, now I want to test the const xyz to the value of the helper function by mocking it out and then returning different things to test if the stuff inside the conditional was done

Comment: It's Enzyme, isn't it? The question doesn't mention that. Also, it's `myFunctionToMock` in one place and `mythingtocheck` in another.

Comment: @estus what do you mean sorry?

Comment: Are you using Enzyme to test the component or what? The question doesn't contain the code you use in tests.

Comment: yes I use enzyme. I have posted parts of the test file. can post more if needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, `myFunctionToMock` is prototype method, it can be mocked as

```
jest.spyOn(MyClass.prototype, 'myFunctionToMock').mockImplementation(...);
```

before class instantiation.

Another option in Enzyme is to disable hooks with [`disableLifecycleMethods` option](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html#shallownode-options--shallowwrapper), mock a method on `wrapper.instance()` and call `componentDidMount` manually.

If a method doesn't belong to `this`, it can be mocked on an object it belongs to:

```
jest.spyOn( helperclass, 'queryParameters').mockImplementation(...);
```

Again, this should be done before class instantiation, or `disableLifecycleMethods` needs to be used.

Comment: i've done that with `.mockImplementation(() => 'mystring'` and it's still logging out in componentDidMount as undefined??

Comment: How exactly did you do this? This shouldn't happen in case you did this as suggested in the answer, i.e. mocking a method before class instantiation.

Comment: I did exactly what you said and added on the `.mockImpl` part above. I've logged it out and it's correctly identifying the function. maybe componentDidMount gets called before?

Comment: looks like it's calling it, just not returning anything?

Comment: In case you're doing everything correctly, it should return mocked value. I cannot say what's wrong in your case without seeing the whole picture. Notice that https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is a requirement for code questions on SO.

Comment: in the function that I'm mocking, I'm actually calling a function inside there. do I need to mock this out too?

Comment: In case you mock myFunctionToMock you don't need to mock functions that are called inside real myFunctionToMock - because they are expected to not be called.

Comment: let me ask it another way. say I have this in `componentDidMount` `const a = helperClass.queryParameters('myparam')` I want to mock out const a. how would I do that? I've tried importing the helperfunction and done `helperFunc.helperMethod.mockImplementation` to try and give `a` that value. does not seem to work?

Comment: Is queryParameters static method? The use of `helperFunc.helperMethod.mockImplementation` is a mistake, unless you already did `jest.spyOn` on this method. Is it `helperFunc.helperMethod` or `this.myFunctionToMock` that needs to be mocked? Please, provide real code you're using in the question. Abstractions don't really help if you have problems applying an answer to them.

Comment: will this be affected by that fact the whole of that helper file is being `jest.mock`ed at the top?

Comment: and I can't find documentation for disabling life cycle methods?

Comment: It depends. In case `queryParameters` was already mocked with `jest.fn()`, this may not be needed. Please, provide *all relevant code*, including your testing code. As I said, MCVE is a requirement. Just to avoid such unclear situations. The link to the documentation is already in the answer, https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html#shallownode-options--shallowwrapper

Comment: you're a legend! it worked. will accept answer. one final question, how can I mock the implementation once? I instantiate the class in the beforeEach, so not sure how I would mock it once in an individual test/

Comment: we posted at same time haha. please see new comment ^^^^^

Comment: Glad it worked. You could mock the module once at the top of test file, `jest.mock(...)`. You can also define a function where you do mocks and reuse it in `beforeEach` when needed.

Comment: it is already mocked at the top using jest.mock('helper', () => ({helperFunc: jest.fn()}))` but then how do you use that in every test? surely it has to be done before it's instantiated like you said? which means I'd have to move `wrapper = shallow etc` outside of the beforeEach and instantiate in every test which isn't ideal :/

Comment: `helperFunc` is already stubbed this way. In case you need to mock it with different values, you need to do `helperFunc.helperMethod.mockImplementation(...)` or `helperFunc.helperMethod.mockReturnValue` before it's used. If values should be different in different tests then you need to move `shallow` from `beforeEach` to `it` or some other way to evaluate it in correct order.

Comment: yeh I had to move to each it block which isn't ideal